# Unable to return the perl Hash into the template toolkit file

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Thanks in advance.
    I am trying to display the list of files using the Template Toolkit file.Before this i        am returning the hash from perl file into the .tt(template toolkit file) file.
    But the condition is not executing and also i am unable to display the list of files.
    For your reference i am providing the files.

### Perl file (Example.pm):

```
sub example{ 
    my $path = "/sa2/tools/jayaram_delete";
    if (chdir($path)) {
        @files = glob "*";//I am getting the list of files
    } else {
        @files = ();
    }

    $run{'files'} = \@files;
    $run{'testing'}= 'files';

    return 'site/screen/screen.tt',\%run;
}
```

### Template toolkit file:(Example.tt)

```
//This is The condition to display the Upload functionality in the .tt file
            [% IF screenName == 'Resource Management' %]
//This is the code given in Stackoverflow,for displaying the list of files getting from    perl file to .tt file.But this functionality is not working in this .tt file.
[% files %]
[% FOREACH n IN files %]
    [% n %]
    [% END %]
//This is the Table format to display the Upload functionality in the .tt file.
<table id='dataTableExample' class=dataTable cellpadding=01 cellspacing=01>

        <tr class=verification style="text-align:left;">
            <th colspan="2">Instrumentation Configuration</th>
        </tr>
    <tr class=controlTableDataRow>
                                    <td class=controlTableCommandCell>
                                             <form    action='/sa/site/screen/testresults/ajaxTab/test/[% parentid %]/[% id %]' method='post'   enctype="multipart/form-data" target='file_upload'>
                                                    <input type="file"  name="uploadFile" size=30>
                                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                                                    <iframe id='file_upload' name='file_upload' style="display:none" src='about:blank' onload="if (file_upload.location.href != 'about:blank') uploadStatus(this)" >
                                                    </iframe>
                                            </form>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
//This is the sample code to display in the .tt file
    <table class=propertyTable cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
    <tr class=propertyTableHeaderRow>
            <th>FileName</th>
            <th>Last Modified Date</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
[% END %]

For your reference i am providing the complete file,please help to solve this problem  for displaying the list of files in .tt file.
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually invokes TT to render the template?

Comment: Are you using Catalyst?

Answer (score 2):

This construction works fine for your aim:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;

my @files = glob "*";
my $tt = Template->new();
my $va = {
    files => \@files
};
$tt->process('my.tt', $va);
```

In my.tt file:

```
[% FOREACH n IN files %]
[% n %]
[% END %]
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response.I tried with the same code by placing in my code but i am not getting any display on the View(Using the template toolkit files)...Is their any problem with my code or any syntax error.Basically i am unable to return the result from the perl file to template tool kit files.Because  i am able to get the list of files in the log's but not in the template files.

Comment: In tt file write [% files %] There is must within something like so 'ARRAY(0x238482)' if not you should taste your code in the perl script.

Comment: For your reference i am placing the my.tt file

Comment: Hi,can any one help me to provide the solution for the above problem.In their  i am providing the .tt files and perl file.Thank you.

Comment: `[% IF screenName == 'Resource Management' %]` Does it works? If not then nothing will work as you see.

Comment: I am using this [% IF screenName %] condition is to restrict the upload functionality only to the single Screen.If i click on "ResourceManagment" page the condition will be true and display the "Upload Functionality" in the template file.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but I just ran across it, and believe I see the issue.  It would appear that you had an extra [% END %] cap in your code, toward the end.  I threw this code into a template, and it did the same thing you're seeing.  Removed the last [% END %] and I got output.  Obviously since I don't have the processing, it wasn't the same output you'd like, but it solved the issue of TT blanking.  I'm sure your problem was resolved long ago, but hopefully this saves someone else some trouble in the future.  Those rogue tags can be a pain with TT.